# angular 13 Passing parameter onclick, in a loop using

Tags: angular13

I have an array of objects. i am iterating that in loop and passing each item's name to onclick which targets a function navigate(url:string) in cmpenent.ts

html :

> {{sousMenu.titre}}

compenent:

> navigate(url:string):void{
> this.router.navigate( [url]);   }

the error message is :
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ngtsc(2345)

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a complete code example so we can advise on the total context.

Sometimes if a property is defined with a type of 'string | undefined' additional handling is needed when the function calls for only a 'string'.

Some of the things you can do are the following:

```
navigate(url:string | undefined):void{ 
this.router.navigate( [url as string]); 
}
```

That might not be the best route but without further viewing of the code it's hard to see how we may expand on it.